# Woocommerce вывод дополнительной информации в админке

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте, есть страница товара в админке, мне нужно вывести доп информацию, которая хранится в бд, вот сюда: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сформировать хук, чтобы вывести сюда доп информацию, и как получить `id` этого поста на этой странице?

P.S. id поста можно конечно получить через `get`, но может есть более правильный вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался, эти штуки называются "метабоксы" `meta_boxes` и добавляются с помощью функции `add_meta_box`, пример кода (нужно добавлять в functions.php своей темы):

```
/* Добавляем блоки в основную колонку на страницах товаров */
function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
    $screens = array( 'product' );
    foreach ( $screens as $screen )
        add_meta_box( 'myplugin_sectionid', 'Название мета блока', 'myplugin_meta_box_callback', $screen );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box');

/* HTML код блока */
function myplugin_meta_box_callback() {
    // Используем nonce для верификации
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'myplugin_noncename' );

    // Информация в метаблоке
    global $post_id;
    echo $post_id.'<br>';
    echo 'Какие-то данные';
}
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если интересно более подробно ознакомиться, введите в гугле "woocommerce добавить метабокс", там будет куча инфы.